# Adding vertical padding to an element increases the height of the element (in addition to the padding)

Tags: html, css, padding

If I have a `<div>` with a `<p>` tag in it and I apply a non-0 padding value to the `<div>`, the height of the `<div>` is increased by the font-size of the `<p>` tag (16px in this case), in addition to the padding. The same applies to the top of the div.  What rule explains this behavior?

This came up when I needed to change the padding of an element with 1px bottom padding to 0 and was surprised when the padding was reduced by much more than 1px.

```css
div.container {
    background-color: peachpuff;
    padding: 25px 12px 0 0;
}

div.container.padding-1{
    padding-bottom:1px;
}

p.text{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: limegreen;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">
        Padding bottom 0
    </p>
</div>

<div class="container padding-1">
    <p class="text">
        Padding bottom 1
    </p>
</div>
```

**Box Model:**

Sorry if its hard to read, the element content height changes from 50 to 34 when padding is reduced by 1.

[image]

Comment: This feels like a collapsing margin issue, coming from the `p` more than the `div`

Comment: If I don't wrap the text in a p I don't see this behavior, so I will investigate adjusting the p's margin, thanks